# Merging two matrices of different size in R

Tags: r, matrix, merge

I've seen a few questions asked about this, but I wasn't able to understand any of the answers and they all seem to be closed threads.

What I'm looking to do is to merge two matrices which have one common column but the other columns are different and the row number is significantly different. I should merge the two matrices in one by checking if any row has a matching column value of the common column.

For example: Matrix 1

```
Matrix 1
Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
a     b    c    d
e     f    g    h
i     j    k    l

Matrix 2
Col1 Col5
a    e
g    f
```

In the above example, the first row in Matrices 1 and two have the same entries in Col1 and Col3, while rows 2 and 3 are dissimilar.

I would like the output to look as follows:

```
NewMatrix
Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5
a     b   c    d    e
e     f   g    h    NA
i     j   k    l    NA
g     NA  NA    NA   f
```

So that the matching rows are joined, while any rows that don't match are simply added on to the end.

Would anyone have an idea of how to do this?

Comment: what I tried is this: dati<-merge(matrix1,matrix2,by=intersect(matrix[,1],matrix2[,1]), all=T)
And I got this error message: Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 
  'by' deve essere compatibile col numero di colonne

Comment: `merge(matrix1,matrix2,all=T)`, in your desired output the last row should be `f` in `Col5` not in `Col3`

Comment: @mtoto Would you care to post this as an answer, so that it can be closed? Alternatively, it's almost certainly possible to find a duplicate - but this is true for most of the questions on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matrices can be merged similarly to `data.frame`'s:

```
merge(matrix1, matrix2, all=TRUE) 
#  Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5
#1    a    b    c    d    e
#2    e    f    g    h <NA>
#3    i    j    k    l <NA>
#4    g <NA> <NA> <NA>    f
```

The result will be a `data.frame` though, you can always convert it back to `matrix`.